# running the script through the specified time in python

Tags: python, list, time

I want to enter a value in a list within a specified time. For example, I want to enter a value in an empty list within 5 minutes, but I want to be able to do this for 5 minutes. When 5 minutes are over, I want to print "time is over" on the screen. How can I do that? I can't use time.sleep() because when I use it, python goes to sleep and I can't enter data at that moment. So in short, I want my script to run for 5 minutes. Finish, when 5 minutes are over. How can I do that?
Thank you.

Comment: I recommend to research the broader aspect of concurrency. The python threading module is probably the easiest way to achieve your task...

Comment: Just run an infinite `while True` loop and break when time's up.

Comment: @ThePyGuy that's not going to exit if using `input` directly and non-blocking input would result in pinning a core to 100% for no real reason.

Comment: Yeah I know that, and event loops can be used in those cases which will just check for the condition even if the process is waiting for user input.

Comment: @TeejayBruno I'll research that now thank you sir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple approach is to use the multiprocessing package. Have a new process to sleep for 5 seconds and let the main one doing the job. A shared state variable can be used to notify the main process when to stop.

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Value
import time

def wait(stop_value, num_of_seconds):
    print('wait called...')
    time.sleep(num_of_seconds)
    stop_value.value = True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('Starting...')
    v_stop = Value('b', False)
    p = Process(target=wait, args=(v_stop, 5,) )
    p.start()
    counter = 0
    while not v_stop.value:
        print(counter)
        time.sleep(1)
        counter = counter + 1
    print('Finished')
```

You may check the docs for more details: https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes

Answer (score 0):

To achieve your goal, you can timeout on asynchronous functions using asyncio.

You have to wrap the blocking `input` function first but Python has first class support for everything to do with async.

```
import asyncio


async def ainput(prompt):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    return await loop.run_in_executor(None, input, prompt)

async def main():
    try:
        text = await asyncio.wait_for(ainput('Enter something in under 5 seconds: '), timeout=5)
        print(f'{text=}')
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        print('\ntime is up!')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```